# Persisting handles of tasks scheduled by ManagedScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, batch-processing, scheduledexecutorservice

This is related to the Timer Service:

> To save a Timer object for future reference, invoke its getHandle
>   method and store the TimerHandle object in a database. (A TimerHandle
>   object is serializable.) To reinstantiate the Timer object, retrieve
>   the handle from the database and invoke getTimer on the handle. A
>   TimerHandle object cannot be passed as an argument of a method defined
>   in a remote or web service interface. In other words, remote clients
>   and web service clients cannot access a bean’s TimerHandle object.
>   Local clients, however, do not have this restriction.

I'd like to know if it is somehow possible to do something similar with tasks scheduled by the `ManagedScheduledExecutorService`.

What I'd like to implement:
I'm working on a web app that displays different reports (e.g. tables, charts etc.) based on corporate data. The user is able to export a specific report to pdf.

Now, I'd like to give the user the possibility to **subscribe** to a specific report, meaning he wants to get that report mailed weekly, monthly, or to whatever time he configures while subscribing. Of course, also **unsubscribing** should be possible at any time, and for this I think I need to refer to some persisted user-related task information (like the handler in the Timer Service) that leads me to the task to be canceled.

The reason why I'm opting for the Executor Service is - as far as I've investigated on - that it is better suited for concurrent batch jobs. The Timer Service schedules all the tasks on a single thread, which might lead to blocking tasks.